# The move from towards toward toward?

Tags: american-english, history

On [this page](http://grammarist.com/spelling/toward-towards/), it is claimed that the usage of "towards" was dominant (I guess both in Britain and America) compared to "toward" until the 19th century when Americans moved toward toward.  (Edit: a Google Books Ngram count is cited for this.)

Is there any research explaining why this is the case?  E.g., was it primarily caused by non-English immigrants, or did a large fraction of immigrants from England for some reason already use "toward"?  Or was it something less organic and more planned like the effort to simplify spellings around this time period (e.g., colour --> color, but this case seems to be more than just a simplified spelling as the pronunciation is different), or just a general "f**k you England, we'll make our language better than yours" attitude?

Comment: What a title. Did you do that on purpose?

Comment: The move was **to** *toward,* no half-way measures those were. :)

Comment: "Is there any research ..." at the OP's end? (As generally expected of questions on ELU)

Comment: @Kris I tried google, though I didn't put a lot of time into it.  Is my question not appropriate for this site?  There seem to be several questions on this site that can be easily answered by google.

Comment: Everyone I know uses *towards* much more than they use *toward*, including myself as an American. I learned this by making an actual study of it using my own personal correspondence both inbound and outbound for over a decade, and was surprised by the unexpected result. Then again, I'm an old man, so perhaps that's it. The only thing most correspondents have in common is they don't let Microsoft tell them what to do and they tend to have a 4-year university degree and often better.

Comment: To start with, perhaps, https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=toward%2C+towards&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctoward%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctowards%3B%2Cc0   Compare: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=toward%2Ctowards&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctoward%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctowards%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @tchrist I use either, as (I see) appropriate to context.

Comment: @tchrist I think it's largely dialectical, though perhaps there's more of a pronounced difference in writing (e.g., see Kris's links).  [This page](http://www.write.com/writing-guides/general-writing/miscellaneous/the-difference-between-toward-and-towards/), which is amusing in various ways, says the Associated Press only accepts "toward."

Comment: @Kris Thanks, I somehow missed this when I first the page I linked.  I just noticed those links you gave are also on that page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the words *toward* and *towards*—as used today in the sense of "in the direction of"—are identical and interchangeable, the choice of which one to use is strictly a style question.

The first U.S. discussion of *toward* versus *towards* that I'm aware of appears in Joseph Hull, [*English Grammar, by Lectures: Comprehending the Principles and Rules of Syntactical Parsing, on a New and Highly Approved System*](https://books.google.com/books?id=J2oVAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA124&dq=%22towards+for+toward+amongst%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RbfhVLiXJYOrogTPjoFI&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22towards%20for%20toward%20amongst%22&f=false), seventh edition (1833):

> Many barbarous words of uncouth sound are still used by our best speakers and writers, notwithstanding there are those of the same import more pleasing to the ear; as *whilst* for while; *amidst* for amid; *downwards* for downward; *upwards* for upward; *towards* for toward; *amongst* for among; *betwixt* for between.

Unfortunately for a modern reader, it isn't clear whether the italicized words are the "barbarous words of uncouth sound" or "those of the same import more pleasing to the ear." On balance I suspect that Hull considered the versions marred by an extra *x* or *s* to be of uncouth sound, but if he meant to condemn *towards*, he was doing so without the backing  of Noah Webster's *An American Dictionary of the English Language* (1828) which treated *toward* and *towards* as interchangeable with regard to the senses "in the direction of," "regarding," "tending to," and "near."

Perhaps the most significant development in the U.S. rivalry between *toward* and *towards* involves the treatment of the two words in the 1847 edition of Webster's *An American Dictionary of the English Language*: Without any explanation, *towards* simply vanishes. And when it reappears in the 1864 edition of that dictionary, it does so only in the form of a one line entry reading "**Towards**. Same as TOWARD." Coequal treatment of the two forms doesn't resume until the arrival of the first *Webster's International Dictionary* (1890).

In any event, the next commenter on *toward* and *towards*, Alfred Ayres, [*The Verbalist*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ab2VxFY5wssC&pg=PA299&dq=%22toward+those+that+profess%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UbzhVOT5KMS0ogTUk4C4AQ&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22toward%20those%20that%20profess%22&f=false) (1896) is less ambiguous about his contemporaries' preferences:

> **Toward.** Those that profess to know about such things say that etymology furnishes no pretext for the adding of *s* to *ward* in such words as *backward*, *forward*, *toward*, *upward*, *onward*, *downward*, *afterward*, *heavenward*, *earthward*, and the like.

U.S. reference works from the past 70 years or so are remarkably consistent in anointing toward as the preferred U.S. spelling, but not one of them analyzes the change in U.S. usage that brought this state of affairs about. From Bergen Evans & Cornelia Evans, *A Dictionary of Contemporary American Usage* (1957):

> **toward; towards.** These forms are both standard English. In Great Britain the form *towards* is heard more often and *toward* is considered archaic or Biblical. In the United States *toward* is the preferred form.

From Theodore Bernstein, *The Careful Writer* (1973):

> **TOWARD(S)** In the United States the favored form is *toward*; in Britain, *towards*. [Cross reference omitted.]

From Roy Copperud, *American Usage and Style: The Consensus* (1980):

> **toward, towards.** The second form is generally considered preferable in Britain, the first in the U.S., though the second is gaining favor in this country. Both, of course, are standard.There is a notion that *towards* goes with tangible objects (*towards a table*) and *toward* with intangibles (*toward an understanding*) but this is fanciful.

From *The Associated Press Stylebook and Libel Manual* (1980):

> **toward** Not *towards*.

From *Webster's Dictionary of English Usage* (1989):

> **toward, towards** Many commentators have observed that *toward* is more common choice in American English, while the preference in British English is for *towards*. Our evidence confirms that such is indeed the case. Both words are commonly used in the U.S., but *toward* is undoubtedly prevalent: [examples omitted]. The British strongly favor *towards*: [examples omitted].
>
> At one time some critics (as Ayres 1881) preferred *toward* because they believed the *-s* of *towards* had died away. Letters from our correspondents sometimes seem to be seeking some semantic basis for a differentiation between the forms, but there is none.

From Kenneth Wilson, *The Columbia Guide to Standard American English* (1993):

> **toward, towards** (*preps*.) *Toward* and *towards* (pronounce them either TORD[Z] or TUH-WORD[Z]) are Standard and interchangeable in meaning. American English uses both, but *toward* more often; British English uses *towards* more.
>
> Patricia O'Conner, *Woe Is I* (1996):
>
> **toward.** No final *s* ("towards"), although that's how they say it in Britain. Similarly, in American English, standard practice is not to add a final *s* to *forward*, *backward*, *upward*, *onward*, *downward*, and so on. [Example omitted.]

From Allan Siegal & William Connolly, *The New York Times Manual of Style and Usage* (1999):

> **toward** (not *towards*).

And from Bryan Garner, *Garner's Modern American Usage* (2003):

> **toward.A. And towards.** In AmE, the preferred form is *toward*; towards is prevalent in BrE. [Cross reference omitted.]

In the book's entry for "DIRECTIONAL WORDS," Garner makes these comments:

> In AmE, the preferred practice is to use the *-ward* form of directional words, as in *toward*, *forward*, and *westward*. Words ending in *-ward* may be either adjectives or adverbs, whereas words ending in *-wards*, common in BrE, may be adverbs only. [List of preferred U.S. forms omitted.]
>
> An exception in AmE is the adverb *backwards*, which is used frequently (though still much less often than *backward*). (It's anomalous that many people who say *forward* also say *backwards*.) ...

So there you have it—decades of observing that *toward* is more prevalent than *towards* in the United States, but no explanation of why.

In my years of work as a freelance and in-house copy editor, I've noticed that U.S. publishers commonly specify the use of *toward*, just as *AP* and *The New York Times* do. Old-fashioned publishers like the idea that all of the books they publish follow a consistent house style—and that, of course, makes an arbitrary style preference self-perpetuating. As publishing moves away from enforcing house styles and toward a "we can't afford to worry about that kind of stuff" model, I think you'll see an increase in the frequency of *towards* in U.S. publications, since the preference for *toward* was never as strong at the manuscript stage as it was on bookstore shelves.

Comment: Wow.  Thank you very much for this detailed and thorough answer.  I found it interesting that the more "archaic" form would become more popular in the US.  Perhaps because of Webster's and others' interests in etymology and simplifications, combined with your good point about publishing houses wanting a consistent style (though for me this is more like a personal word choice than a spelling convention).  And I suppose I need to read Hull's book to parse his sentence.

Comment: @Kimball: Shakespeare used both *toward* and *towards*, and both forms go back to Old English. How can you call one "more archaic"?

Comment: Very thorough answer. I wonder if you've any thoughts on why 'backward(s), upward(s), downward(s)' etc all stress the first syllable in speech, whereas 'toward(s)' stresses the second, even when pronounced as 'tord(z)'?

Comment: @PeterShor I was referring to the Evans & Evans dictionary quote.  Also, I thought I read somewhere that _toward_ was older--I forget where now, but the Ayres quote and [this wiktionary etymology entry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/towards) seem to support this.