# 'Downwards' versus 'Downward'

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, differences, ward-wards

I was memorizing a specific sentence in a passage about photography, and I accidentally made a mistake of memorizing 'downward' as 'downwards'. I'm a non-native English speaker so I'm not quite familiar with subtle distinctions like this. Is there any contextual or grammatical difference between these two?

Here's the sentence:

> Using the camera at your own head height works well for photographing adults, but for children will be tilted **downward**.

Comment: They're equivalent and interchangeable. The only real difference is that historically, [*Brits used to favour **downwards**.*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=downward%2Cdownwards&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdownward%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdownwards%3B%2Cc0) But [*Americans always liked **downward** better*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=downward%2Cdownwards&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdownward%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdownwards%3B%2Cc0), and we're falling into line now.

Comment: ...which is the same with, for example, ***backward/backwards, forward/forwards, upward/upwards***. But (rather curiously, imho) it's markedly "American" to use ***anyways*** instead of ***anyway*** as a colloquial "interjectory conjunction".

Comment: God I've always wondered the difference between anyways and anyway.. Thanks again for the additional explanation!

Comment: I think Americans are more likely to adopt "folksy regionalisms" into mainstream colloquial contexts (usually, with a degree of "facetiousness"). So besides ***anyways***, you'll often hear ***anyhoo*** (from ***anyhow***, which I *think* was originally a ***Scottish*** dialectalism, but I haven't checked).

Comment: As FumbleFingers says, they're interchangeable. For more, see the treatise on toward/towards here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227755/the-move-from-towards-toward-toward/227797#227797

Comment: @KJO: I think your "distinction" there is a peculiarity of ***idiolect*** (arguably, ***idiosyncratic*** at that), rather that a meaningful nuance as recognised by any meaningful number of speakers. But if that's how you roll, who am I to argue with it?

Comment: ...having said that, Brits used to be more likely to use ***downwards*** in "adverbial" contexts such as [(he) moved downwards.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=moved+downward%2Cmoved+downwards&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmoved%20downward%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmoved%20downwards%3B%2Cc0) We never much liked the "adjectival" form [a downwards path.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+downward+path%2Ca+downwards+path&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20downward%20path%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @KJO: I'm a bit "unjustifiably dismissive" of questions like this on ELU. I closevoted purely because I was irritated by the fact that the OP here is clearly a non-native speaker seeking to ***learn*** some detail about how the language is used. And *in the specific context* (of *to be tilted downwards / downward / down*) I see no semantic implications in the choice. But if this had been asked on ELL (where it *should* be), I might have posted an answer myself - in which context it would be at least "interesting" to flag US/UK and "leading adjective" /"post-positioned adverb" differences.

Answer (score 0):

FumbleFingers commented:

> They're equivalent and interchangeable. The only real difference is that historically,
>
> [Brits used to favour **downwards**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=downward%2Cdownwards&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdownward%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdownwards%3B%2Cc0%22)
>
> but
>
> Americans always liked **downward** better
>
> –  and we're falling into line now.
>
> ... which is the same with, for example, *backward/backwards*,
> *forward/forwards*, *upward/upwards*.
>
> But (rather curiously, imho) it's markedly "American" to use *anyways*
> instead of *anyway* as a colloquial "interjectory conjunction".
>
> ...
>
> I think Americans are more likely to adopt "folksy regionalisms" into
> mainstream colloquial contexts (usually, with a degree of
> "facetiousness"). So besides anyways, you'll often hear anyhoo (from
> anyhow, which I think was originally a Scottish dialectalism, but I
> haven't checked).

I'd add that 'upwards mobility' is far rarer than 'upward mobility' even in the UK; this (dropping the s) is probably the case with other strong collocates/compounds (forward thinking; backward-looking ...). [EA]